# Facebook page acquire full screen after clicking on iframe

Tags: facebook

i am trying to open facebook authentication page in IFRAME that i have created on my page
but the problem is once the page get loaded into iframe and i click on an iframe the facebook authentication page acquires the whole page in a full screen and iframe get vanish.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<id>&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3662/test.web/pages/z.aspx&display=popup
```

here is my url that i am setting in iframe src attribute

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this myself.  The solution I used?

[Javascript Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/javascript)

And the rough steps

```
// trigger this any way you want
window.open(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&display=popup&scope=PERM_LIST&redirect_url=http://example.com/oauth_redirect'
  , 'authorize'
  , 'width=600,height=350'
);
```

This displays the authentication window in a popup.  Now, the next bit what you do with the redirect url (in my example, `http://example.com/oauth_redirect`)

The access_token parameter in the URL holds the OAuth token - so retrieve that and do whatever you need to with it (store in a cookie, whatever).  And then use JS to control what happens to the popup and opener

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Perhaps load the next page?
window.opener.location = 'http://example.com/canvas'

// close the popup
window.close();

</script>
```

See [this relevant forum thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=56590) as well.

Comment: parameter name is `redirect_uri`, not `redirect_url`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that, but I think the "popup" form factor is for real popups, you should try the "page" form factor here

Comment: do you mean it doesn't initially open in the iframe or when you click on the authorize button it takes over the page as well?

Comment: i it opening in a iframe window successfully but when a user clicks inside an iframe , the whole page get loaded with a facebook page.

Comment: hum, on second though this sounds rather logical. There's a redirect at the end of the process and I you cannot redirect _inside_ an iframe. I am afraid you will have to use a real popup :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a security mechanism; the user has little way to tell whether your IFRAME is really Facebook, or you presenting something that looks like Facebook. With a full URL at the top, this becomes much more transparent (yes, they should implement SSL with a valid cert to truly prove this, but hey).

Comment: The workaround is to redirect to the Facebook authentication page specifying the page you want to return to when done ase per: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web

Answer (score 0):

Login in iframe is not allowed for security reasons. Use a popup instead. You can do what Peter suggested with `window.open` or use the JS SDK, for example: http://fbrell.com/auth/all-in-one.