# facebook login page in lightbox

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook page acquire full screen after clicking on iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201665/facebook-page-acquire-full-screen-after-clicking-on-iframe)

I want to open facebook login page in a lightbox.

if i tried to open facebook page in iframe then after loading successfully , in case a user click on an iframe , facebook will cover the whole page.

But i want to open it in lightbox

Answer (score 0):

Please do not re-post your question multiple times.

[Facebook page acquire full screen after clicking on iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201665/facebook-page-acquire-full-screen-after-clicking-on-iframe/)